# Dynamics CRM Unified Service Desk Popup Result

Tags: dynamics-crm, unified-service-desk

We are using Dynamics CRM 2016 with USD 2.0 and are having problems with popups within the system returning results.

There are several places where we open webresources in new windows (as floating panels), do some work in the new window then need to interact with the parent window to set some fields.

This works perfectly in a browser using window.open and window.parent.Xrm... to set the value. However in USD, the window.parent variable is null and we cannot find any other way to get the parent window to set a value.

Any help or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a two-part challenge.  The first challenge involves ensuring that your Web Resources are actually being loaded within USD, in Hosted Controls rather than external browser windows.  The second challenge involves communicating between the Hosted Controls involved, once everything is happening within USD.

In USD, if window.open is launching external browser windows, then your Window Navigation Rules (or lack thereof) are allowing your Web Resource navigations to leave USD.  To pass values as needed here, it's necessary to reign in such navigations using Window Navigation Rules.  Define a Hosted Control that lives on FloatingPanel, and experiment with Rules until your Web Resources are loading as desired.

If the Web Resource is loading in a Hosted Control, then it just needs to speak USD.  When it's time to return values, check if window.IsUSD, and raise a custom Event:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn864970.aspx#EventMoniker

This will allow you to write Action Calls that can consume your Event's key-value-pairs, which are accessible using [[replacement syntax]] during the Event.  These Action Calls can RunXrmCommand on your "parent" control (which USD is simply treating as some other non-parent hosted browser), so your return values can ultimately find their way.

Comment: Thanks for this. Have decided to go the approach of raising a custom event and tracking the origin page by passing parameters to the webresource on trigger.